# Powershell Foreach where-object -eq value

Tags: powershell, foreach

If I import a csv of computer names $computers that looks like this

```
Host
----
computer5
Computer20
Computer1
```

and import another csv of data $data that looks like this

```
Host        OS         HD    Capacity Owner
----        --         --    ------   -----
Computer20  Windows7   C      80      Becky
Computer1   Windows10  C      80      Tom
Computer1   Windows10  D      100     Tom
computer5   Windows8   C      100     sara
computer5   Windows8   D      1000    sara
computer5   Windows8   E      1000    sara
```

Im trying to do this

```
foreach ($pc in $computers){
                          $hostname = $pc.host
                          foreach ($entry in $data | where {$enty.host -eq $hostname})
                              {write-host "$entry.Owner"}
                          }
```

The foreach statement isn't finding any matches. How can I fix this?
Im trying to do more than just write the owner name but, this is the basic premise

Thanks!
Steve

Comment: For such single operator conditions, you can simplify like this: `where host -eq $hostname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$enty` with `$_` inside the `Where-Object` filter block:

```
foreach ($entry in $data |Where-Object {$_.host -eq $hostname}){
  Write-Host $entry.Owner
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, using an array `$computers.host` on the left side of the -eq operator:

```
$computers = 'Host
computer5
Computer20
Computer1' | convertfrom-csv

$data = 'Host,OS,HD,Capacity,Owner
Computer20,Windows7,C,80,Becky
Computer1,Windows10,C,80,Tom
Computer1,Windows10,D,100,Tom
computer5,Windows8,C,100,sara
computer5,Windows8,D,1000,sara
computer5,Windows8,E,1000,sara' | convertfrom-csv

$data | where { $computers.host -eq $_.host } | ft

Host       OS        HD Capacity Owner
----       --        -- -------- -----
Computer20 Windows7  C  80       Becky
Computer1  Windows10 C  80       Tom
Computer1  Windows10 D  100      Tom
computer5  Windows8  C  100      sara
computer5  Windows8  D  1000     sara
computer5  Windows8  E  1000     sara
```

Or

```
$data | where host -in $computers.host
```

Or

```
foreach ( $entry in $data | where host -in $computers.host | foreach owner ) { 
  $entry }

Becky
Tom
Tom
sara
sara
sara
```

Assuming $entry is spelled correctly, this syntax just happens not to work.

The expression `$data | where {$entry.host -eq $hostname}` just doesn't make sense by itself.  Good question though.  You can indeed use a pipeline in the parens after foreach.

```
foreach ($pc in $computers){
  $hostname = $pc.host
  foreach ($entry in $data | where {write-host "entry is $entry";
           $entry.host -eq $hostname}){
    write-host "$entry.Owner"
  }
}

entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
entry is
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the different ways of doing this. I always take examples like this and store them for future use. I appreciate the help.